# what is the cause of the first atom moving in moving?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, atoms

I'm a computer student and I know nothing about physics and `physics.stackexchange`, so if I did something wrong, tell me to correct it (for example tagging). and sorry if my question is silly.

the thing is I can't understand the causality of moving and I'm thinking for hours with no conclusion so I'm here for getting help.

**definition:** a *moving* atom is an atom which its displacement vector is bigger that 1nm per second.

> let's assume there is you and a ball in front of you in complete void
>   (no gravity, temperature is 0k out of your special suit, etc) and no
>   atom is *moving* in the ball and your hands and your suit.
>
> suddenly you hit the ball and now all the atoms in the ball are *moving*, so you must have *moved* the atoms of your suit, so you must have *moved* the atoms of your hand and so on.
>
> how did the first atom move? what is the cause?

sorry if I couldn't make my question well-defined, it is about moving but as atoms in our bodies are always moving, it is hard for me to make the moving act well-defined. I hope you'll understand my question.

thanks in advance for helping me understand.

Comment: A nerve signal in your brain causes your muscles to move via a chemical reaction. Hence you hand and arm start moving to hit the ball.

Comment: @MaxW chemical reaction are moving atoms aren't them?

Comment: The electrical currents in your brain are caused by moving atoms (or ions) and cause moving atoms (or ions).

Comment: @Ertxiem, thanks. I just searched about ions and thanks to this youtube video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWc3k2723IM] now I undrstand. so electrons suplying in our brain can movie some ions which leads to moving our whole hand. nice fact!